# Iterating over variable name in bash script

Tags: bash

I needed to run a script over a bunch of files, which paths were assigned to `train1`, `train2`, ... , `train20`, and I thought 'why not make it automatic with a bash script?'.

So I did something like:

```
train1=path/to/first/file
train2=path/to/second/file
...
train20=path/to/third/file

for i in {1..20}
do
    python something.py train$i
done
```

which didn't work because `train$i` echoes `train1`'s name, but not its value.

So I tried unsuccessfully things like `$(train$i)` or `${train$i}` or `${!train$i}`.
Does anyone know how to catch the correct value of these variables?

Comment: Oh, I could python something.py each_filename, but later I need to run some other scripts over the same files, that's why i put it on those variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array:

```
train[1]=path/to/first/file
train[2]=path/to/second/file
...
train[20]=path/to/third/file

for i in {1..20}
do
    python something.py ${train[$i]}
done
```

Or eval, but it awfull way:

```
train1=path/to/first/file
train2=path/to/second/file
...
train20=path/to/third/file

for i in {1..20}
do
    eval "python something.py $train$i"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this structure with square brackets some kind of dictionary?

Comment: @rafa It's the way get reference to array element. [Some kind of short manual.](http://augix.com/wiki/Arrays%20in%20Bash.html)

Comment: Simpler is `for train in "${trains[@]}"`. Of course, the array variable name should be plural :)

Answer (score 9):

Use an array.

Bash does have variable indirection, so you can say

```
for varname in train{1..20}
do
    python something.py "${!varname}"
done
```

The `!` introduces the indirection, so "get the value of the variable named by the value of varname"

But use an array. You can make the definition very readable:

```
trains=(
    path/to/first/file
    path/to/second/file
    ...
    path/to/third/file
)
```

Note that this array's first index is at position zero, so:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#trains[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "train $i is ${trains[$i]}"
done
```

or

```
for idx in "${!trains[@]}"; do
    echo "train $idx is ${trains[$idx]}"
done
```